# How do you force create a new monero address on coinomi?

Tags: third-party-wallets

A withdrawal from an exchange has been pending and I need to make a second withdrawal but I don't wan't to link to the first by sending to the same address. Is there any way to force coinomi android to create a new address before receiving a payment? What about just opening monero core and creating a new address with the same seed. Will coinomi pick it up?

---

It appears that pressing the refresh symbol by payment id creates a new address and random payment id. Can someone confirm this is the correct way to send a second payment to coinomi as I thought payment id was being redacted by monero.

---

Also, on the Monero Gui client (non-coinomi), is it possible to remove added accounts or addresses that are unused. Like if I created 10 accounts, can I delete 9 from the GUI without reinstalling?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the official coinomi response:
If you need a completely separate address for this monero TX then you can add a second wallet from +coins. In Coinomi you cannot select which UTXOs are spent in each transaction, this is automatically done by the app.

The 'refresh' icon on the receive page, creates an integrated address - this address is the same receive address with a payment ID attached.

Monero Core/Coinomi: you can use the recovery tool listed at the bottom of our recovery guide for converting your Coinomi phrase to be used in the monero wallet. However, this is not needed since you can add a second XMR wallet in Coinomi (+coins) or simply just use the one address. - You will be happy to know that we have plans to add XMR sub-address support in the future too.

Hope this helps

Kind Regards,
Coinomi Support